# TypeScript debug error - the breakpoint not currently be hit - when use special character

Tags: javascript, typescript, special-characters

Suddenly faced with the problem:

TypeScript debug error - the breakpoint not currently be hit - when use special character. 
Was wondered - the reason - using of special characters [`calendar`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4c5/index.htm)

```
Template("", ...
```

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution

```
.Template("&#128197;", ...
```